# AMCL laser scan, TF, Rviz problem

Tags: navigation, rviz, transform, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1)I am doing a project on AMCL of a quadcopter and now I am facing a problem where my laser scan couldn't work (running stage simulator,willow-full.world).

```
**Error:
[ WARN] [1379926948.092017939, 127.500000000]: No laser scan received (and thus no pose updates have been published) for 127.500000 seconds.  Verify that data is being published on the /scan topic.**
```

I have another question,

2. What should I do in order to localize my robot on rviz with exact map while I am running it on stage simulator? By creating a static tf? How should I do?

Ps: Using Fuerte ROS

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/82206/amcl-laser-scan,-tf,-rviz-problem/) by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2013-09-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Martin,

I remember that I needed to remap the laser-scan topic (default: "/scan") in order to make it work with AMCL... my launchfile is something like this (most of the parameters are taken 1-by-1 from the AMCL tutorial):

```
<launch>
<node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(find husky_simulation_fh_ac)/map/gasstation.yaml"/>

<node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl" output="screen">
    <remap from="scan" to="hokuyo_scan"/>
    <param name="odom_frame_id" value="odom_combined"/>
    <param name="odom_model_type" value="diff"/>
    <param name="laser_model_type" value="likelihood_field"/>
    <param name="use_map_topic" value="false"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha5" value="0.1"/>
    <param name="transform_tolerance" value="0.2" />
    <param name="gui_publish_rate" value="10.0"/>
    <param name="laser_max_beams" value="30"/>
    <param name="min_particles" value="500"/>
    <param name="max_particles" value="5000"/>
    <param name="kld_err" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="kld_z" value="0.99"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha1" value="0.2"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha2" value="0.2"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha3" value="0.8"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha4" value="0.2"/>
    <param name="laser_z_hit" value="0.5"/>
    <param name="laser_z_short" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="laser_z_max" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="laser_z_rand" value="0.5"/>
    <param name="laser_sigma_hit" value="0.2"/>
    <param name="laser_lambda_short" value="0.1"/>
    <param name="laser_lambda_short" value="0.1"/>
    <param name="laser_likelihood_max_dist" value="2.0"/>
    <param name="update_min_d" value="0.2"/>
    <param name="update_min_a" value="0.5"/>
    <param name="resample_interval" value="1"/>
    <param name="transform_tolerance" value="0.1"/>
    <param name="recovery_alpha_slow" value="0.0"/>
    <param name="recovery_alpha_fast" value="0.0"/>
</node>
 </launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [psei](https://answers.ros.org/users/6031/psei/) with karma: 318 on 2013-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-10-08**:
Hi psei, the question was asked by FuerteNewbie, I just changed the formatting (parts of the question were invisible before).

**Comment by [psei](https://answers.ros.org/users/6031/psei/) on 2013-10-08**:
Ah ok, I just saw it